# expiration of stored objects using localstorage anf garlicjs

Tags: jquery, local-storage

I'm using `garlic.js` for data storage and I want data to be persisted for some time even after form is submitted.

I'm using the `data-expires` attribute for this purpose but data is not being stored even when `data-destroy="false"`

Answer (score 0):

I have found a plugin that does this, I didn't write it so cant take caredit but it works like a charm. Try this :

https://code.google.com/p/local-cache/